# Changing from local server to web host but keeping mail in local server

Tags: email, web, host

I am trying to shift my client's website from their local server to a web host, they pointed domain to my web host ip address (A record), however, it does not work.

I understand that if I were to change the DNS and point the nameservers to my web host, I will lose the data in the mail server which they still want to host in their local server.

What should I do? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a DNS record for the local server. When you have done this, your client will need to point their mail clients at the new DNS record to access email. Inbound email for the domain will need to be routed via your domain's MX records.

Example:

- The A record for `example.com` will point to the webhost.
- The A record for `mail.example.com` will point to the local server.
- The MX record for `example.com` will point to `mail.example.com`